# Failing to use react html 5 video in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, next.js, html5-video

I just installed the package but I keep getting this error from nextjs

**./src/assets/Vido.mp4
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)**

When I follow the link to the loaders page, I do not understand what exactly I'm supposed to do to fix the problem.

This is how my file structure looks like **src** is the root folder, then I have the **components** and **assets** folder. Inside the assets folder, I have the video and then in the components folder, I have the vid.js file and this is how it looks like

```
import React from 'react'
import { DefaultPlayer as Video } from 'react-html5video'
import cook from "../assets/Vido.mp4"

const videouri = cook;

function Vid() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Video 
            width="400" 
            controls 
            autoPlay={model}
            muted playsInline 
        >
            <source src={videouri} type="video/webm" />
        </Video>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Vid
```

Where exactly am I going wrong and how I fix it?.